# How do I add different size of new array to an old array using a for loop?

Tags: c, for-loop

How do I use a `for` loop to add array `1` to array `2` and become the expected array like the example below?

What I expect is adding the first element in array `1` to array `2`'s second `1234` and continue adding up:

```
Array 1 = [4, 8]

Array 2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Expected Array:

```
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

I am thinking of something like this, but just feel very strange.

```
N=4
for (int i=N; i<array.size; i++)
{
   array2[i] = array1[...];

}
```

Comment: Could you please eleborate on how two arrays should be combined. Like is the second array always processed in terms of quadruplets and is the first group always excluded. Also kindly asking: is this for somekind of assigment?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what the relationship between these 3 array are. You need to explain that.

Comment: @Ackdari yeah it is in terms of quadruplets, and nope is not somekind of assignment I just comeover a idea for my personal project and Im stucked

Comment: @MIT Ok, a little more context about the nature of the problem you are solving might help us understand better how to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your question is when

```
int array1[] = {4, 8};

int array2[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4};
```

```
int arrayAnswer[] = {array2[0],array2[1],array2[2],array2[3],
array2[0]+array1[1],array2[1]+array1[1],array2[2]+array1[1],array2[3]+array1[1],
array2[0]+array1[2],array2[1]+array1[2],array2[2]+array1[2],array2[3]+array1[2]}
```

is it right? if so, please leave the comment and I will edit more

First of all, the question you made is not a good question. Please try to give more detailed information about your problem next time.

Answer for your question is, skip fist four member of array and add `array1[1]` on from `array2[4] to array [7]`, and add `array1[2]` on from `array2[8] to array [11]`. You are going to need two loop. such as

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++){
   for (j = 0; j < 4; j++){
      //your function
   }
}
```

I am not going to give you direct answer for the problem so that you can design your own. However, if your first array is `{0, 4, 8}`, your coding is going to be much easier. ty

Comment: yes exactly, this is what i expected to do, is it possible to do in a for loop?